Update OT problem (sinkhorn-knopp) from SwAV
I'm using SwAV to learn a representation of my data, and I need to update the optimal transport problem behind it, but I don't have enough knowledge in OT to do that.
Here is the OT problem behind SwAV:
Given two sets of features $(\mathbf{z_i})_{i=1}^N$ and $(\mathbf{c_j})_{j=1}^K$, where
$\mathbf{z_i} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are the features of the samples and $\mathbf{c_j} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are the prototypes,
the goal is to find the optimal transport plan $\mathbf{Q}^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$ as below:
$$
    \mathbf{Q}^{*} = \text{argmax}_{\mathbf{Q} \in P} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^K Q_{ij} \left(\mathbf{z_i}^\top \mathbf{c_j} - \epsilon \log Q_{ij}\right),
$$
where $P$ is the transportation polytope defined as:
$$
    P = \left\{ \mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}_+ \mid \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{1}_K = \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{1}_N, \, \mathbf{Q}^\top \mathbf{1}_N = \frac{1}{K} \mathbf{1}_K \right\}.
$$
Here, $\epsilon$ is a regularization parameter, $Q_{ij}$ represents the assignment of feature $\mathbf{z_i}$ to prototype $\mathbf{c_j}$, $\mathbf{1}_N$ and $\mathbf{1}_K$ are vectors of ones of sizes $N$ and $K$, respectively.
In the main article, this is solved using the Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm.
The thing is, in my case, my feature vectors belongs to a certain category among $T$ categories. That is, $\forall i, C(\mathbf{\mathbf{z_i}}) \in [\![1, T]\!]$ is the category of the feature vector $\mathbf{z_i}$.
I don't want to enfore the assignments to be balanced for a specific category, but I want them to be balanced for the categories overall.
Therefore, $P$ is now the following:
$$
    P = \left\{ \mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}_+ \mid \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{1}_K = \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{1}_N, \, \forall k, \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{\sum_n Q_{nk}\mathbf{1}_{\{t\}}(C_n)}{\sum_n{\mathbf{1}_{\{t\}}(C_n)}} = \frac{1}{K} \right\}.
$$
Do you have any idea how I could update the OT problem to take this into account?
